# Angular 6 return mapping missing

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Upgrading a project from Angular 4 to 6 and having some trouble getting my return to work. My json comes in like

```
{
    "incomingViolationList":[{"productName": "Mirror",…],
    "incomingViolationListCount": 67
}
```

My service call use to look like this but in A6 .map no longer works.

```
return this.http.get('MappViolations/MappViolations?', options)
      .map(response => <GridDataResult>{
        data: response.json().incomingViolationList,
        total: response.json().incomingViolationListCount
      });
```

I have starting my new service call but am at a loss how to seperate into "data" and "total"

```
return this.http.get<IncommingViolations[]>
      (AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'MappViolations/MappViolations?', { params });
```

Comment: But what is happening?

Comment: in the A4 version .map is no longer a option

Comment: use pipe and then map.

Comment: Perhaps helpfully, read https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md It comes with a change in rxjs, where chained dot-operators were replaced with pipe/taps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 6, you will be using HttpClient which returns the json response by default. So you can remove json from the response.

```
return this.http.get('MappViolations/MappViolations?', options)
     .pipe( 
 map(response => ({
  data: response.incomingViolationList, //<-- remove json
  total: response..incomingViolationListCount //<-- remove json
 })
```

);

Comment: I am using httpclient. But this is the A4 code. How do I translate from .map down into A6?

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 6 there is HttpClient used instead of Http service

> Using HttpClient the response object is a JSON by default, so there's no need to parse it anymore (`response.json()` is not needed)

Also if you update RxJS 6 with Angular 6 update it will look something like below `pipe`able operators.

```
return this.http.get('MappViolations/MappViolations?', options)
  .pipe( 
     map((response: any) => ({
      data: response.incomingViolationList,
      total: response..incomingViolationListCount
     })
  );
```

Comment: ok, I think this is almost there. I am getting the following error.



[ts] Property 'incomingViolationList' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: or use `map((response: {incomingViolationList: any, incomingViolationListCount: any}) => ({`

Answer (score -1):

So you have stated in the comment that your case is that *map is not an option*. Well actually it still is, but it is used slightly different way

```
return this.http.get('MappViolations/MappViolations?', options)
      .pipe(
        map(response => <GridDataResult>{
          data: response.json().incomingViolationList,
          total: response.json().incomingViolationListCount
      }));
```

Notice usage of `pipe` directly on observable insteed of `map`.